# Quarkus and provided dependencies (sapjco3.jar)

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, sap-erp

I currently try to migrate an old Java EE solution that connects via RFC to a SAP-System to an approach with Quarkus.
As the project uses maven, I face again the issue of the sapjco3.jar library from SAP that prevents the library from being renamed.
If I add the library as dependency like that

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sap</groupId>
          <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

it will be added to the lib-directory with the name *com.sap.sapjco3-3.1.jar*.
Unfortunately that ends up in an excpetion

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Illegal JCo archive "com.sap.sapjco3-3.1.jar". It is not allowed to rename or repackage the original archive "sapjco3.jar".

There are already some articles on Stackoverflow describing that issue and there is also a SAP-note on that: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2182414

So I solved the issue in the "old" approach, setting the dependency to provided and copying it with the maven-dependency-plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeArtifactIds>sapjco3</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Unfortunately that does not work with quarkus.
In development if I use

```
mvn quarkus:dev
```

the *provided* seems to be ignored and I still get the message.

> JCo initialization failed with java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Illegal JCo archive "sapjco3-3.1.jar". It is not allowed to rename or repackage the original archive "sapjco3.jar".

If I pack it and try to deploy it to a docker-container

```
mvn clean package
```

it basically works to copy the jar-file to the lib-directory, if I change the copy to another phase in the pom.xml

```
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
</goals>
```

but I get build warnings first:

> [WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index com.sap.conn.jco.ext.DestinationDataProvider: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader

> [INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: com.sap.conn.jco.ext.DestinationDataProvider was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.

and later the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/ext/DestinationDataProvider

Is there a solution with Quarkus to deal with provided dependencies and copy them manually with maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the SAP library working with Quarkus in a project. The solution is not specific to Quarkus (the same solution is used by Spring Boot projects).

First, define the library with a system scome so that its name is not modified.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sap</groupId>
  <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.build.directory}/dependency/sapjco3.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Then, configure the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy the library in this path in the initialize phase and to include it in the final package. It also contains configuration for the native lib used by the sapjco3.jar library.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-jco-libs-unit-tests</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
          <outputDirectory>${lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
              <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
              <version>${sap.jco.version}</version>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
              <destFileName>sapjco3.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-native-lib-for-unit-tests</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
          <outputDirectory>${native.lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
              <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
              <version>${sap.jco.version}</version>
              <type>${envType}</type>
              <classifier>${envClassifier}</classifier>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
              <destFileName>${native.lib.filename}.${envType}</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Last, configure which native lib should be included thanks to profiles, one profile by OS/CPU arch is needed. Here is the configuration:

```
<profiles>
<!-- Manage JCO native deps by OS arch -->
<profile>
  <id>windows-x86_64</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>windows</family>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
    <envType>dll</envType>
    <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>windows-amd64</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>windows</family>
      <arch>amd64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
    <envType>dll</envType>
    <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>linux-x86_64</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <name>linux</name>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <envClassifier>linuxx86_64</envClassifier>
    <envType>so</envType>
    <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>linux-amd64</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <name>linux</name>
      <arch>amd64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <envClassifier>linuxx86_64</envClassifier>
    <envType>so</envType>
    <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>macosx-x86_64</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <name>mac os x</name>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <envClassifier>darwinintel64</envClassifier>
    <envType>dylib</envType>
    <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>macosx-amd64</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <name>mac os x</name>
      <arch>amd64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <envClassifier>darwinintel64</envClassifier>
    <envType>dylib</envType>
    <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

With all this, test works, `mvn quarkus:dev` works, and a package done with `mvn clean package` works.

**Be careful that the initialize phase of Maven is not launched by default**, you need to call `mvn initialize` once for the library copy to happens.

Comment: That works very well for ````mvn quarkus:dev````. Unfortunately ````mvn package```` still adds *com.sap.sapjco3.jar* while copying to *target/lib* folder.
I will try to find a solution for that last issue, too.

Comment: It should not be the case, did you run a `mvn clean` before?

Comment: As there is a systemPath and the lib scope is system it will not download the lib at package time and use the one from the system path so it's not renamed.

Comment: Yes, I did a mvn clean.
Nevertheless, I am forced by maven to do a local install ``mvn install:install-file -DgroupId="com.sap" -DartifactId=sapjco3 -Dversion="3.1" -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="target/dependency/sapjco3.jar"`` and I guess even on system scope it is doing a download from that local repository than?

Comment: With the proposed setup, using `mvn clean`, then `mvn initialize` then `mvn quarkus:dev` and finally `mvn package` works.
The sapjco3.jar lib is on my corporate Maven repo so maven download it, then put it in the systemPath configured without modifying it's name.

Answer (score 0):

We were struggling and working around with the naming-problem of the sapjco3.jar until I stumbled upon a footnote on this link: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/It-is-not-allowed-to-rename-or-repackage-the-original-archive-sapjco3-jar

Name your artifact `com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3.jar` and it will solve the naming problem, as the driver accepts this name even with versions numbers added.

Your next stumbling block will then be the native library though ... I don't have a solution for that part in a quarkus environment, as I didn't try that yet.